# Fields that are subclasses of type Serializable trigger a warning to be made Serializable by SonarQube

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube, sonarlint

Let's say we have some class:

```
class Foo implements Serializable { }
```

And some interface:

```
interface Bar extends Serializable { }
```

If we have an implementation like this:

```
class X implements Bar { 
    private final Foo foo; 
}
```

SonarQube will warn that fields should be Serializable or transient in class X. `foo` in this case is-a `Serializable` so why does this warning appear? Does the type of `foo` explicitly need to be `Serializable` despite already being Serializable through inheritance?

## Environment

Verified on SonarLint 6.7.0.45926 connected to SonarQube Enterprise Edition Version 7.9.4 (build 35981), as well as SonarLint standalone 6.7.0.45926 in IntelliJ.

Comment: Could you please specify which version of SonarQube do you use?

Comment: Verified on SonarLint 6.7.0.45926 connected to SonarQube Enterprise Edition Version 7.9.4 (build 35981), as well as SonarLint standalone 6.7.0.45926 in IntelliJ

Comment: What is the specific SolarLint rule number that is being triggered?

Comment: s1948: Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable